# Why my HP computer is getting blocked when It turns on?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, freeze

My HP computer is windows 10 and I bought it many years ago, sometimes when I turn it ON, the screen gets blocked on this blue screen and I do not know why is this happening.

I have already disconnected all the cables, wait a long time to turn it on, etc, In fact, it has another little problem that I do not know If it could be entwined with this issue, when I turn it OFF and I try to turn it ON again, the PC does not show anything on the screen,and it seems not to have any connection with the PC.

I have already run diagnostics and everything seems to be well

First Image (Here is where the computer is getting)

[image]

Second Image (As you can see in the right corner, this is where I turn it on and it generally changes to its normal color, which is blue, but sometimes it doesn't have any color, and the computer seems to work normally inside the CPU, in the left there is a little "button" which should light it orange when the computer is working properly; otherwise it still turns off)

[image]

Third Image (More specifications)

[image]

Comment: Sounds like a hardware failure. Could be a fan, could be the PSU, could even be the motherboard. Then again, that system is really old and simply needs to be replaced. Fixing the hardware may prolong it with a few more months, but in my professional opinion is not worth the costs, similar as to how an old car will get to a point where repairing it will cost way more than replacing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- While according to the HP.com website, this model was released in 2011, you should open it up, look at the motherboard, and check for leaking capacitors anyway.  The Wikipedia article on [the capacitor plague](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor_plague) has illustrations and explains what it is more exactly.

  If you do have leaking capacitors on the motherboard, you should plan to stop using this system as soon as possible and move to a new system.
- A second possible cause of this is the system trying to boot off of a USB device.  Ensure no USB devices are connected while starting the system.
- Afterward, it may be that the power supply is failing.  You might be able to source a replacement power supply for this system cheap off of your favorite auction site and replace it, but unless you can find one really cheap and are willing to do it yourself, you're better off putting the money toward a new system.